# Access - Show values from subform in texboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form "frm_Results" with subform "subfrm_shv_Results" and three textboxes ("txt_Number", "txt_Name", 'txt_Surname").

[image: frm_Results]

I can show values of selected record in `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox`:

`Debug.Print Form_frm_Results.subfrm_shv_Results.Form!Number.Value`

`Debug.Print Form_frm_Results.subfrm_shv_Results.Form!Name.Value`

`Debug.Print Form_frm_Results.subfrm_shv_Results.Form!Surname.Value`

But it is possible to show values of "Number", "Name" and "Surname" in textboxes after click on record in subform "subfrm_shv_Results"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, with a query as the contained object, you need to refer to the [controls property](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs,_forms_and_updating), for example, you can set the control source of a textbox to :

```
= [Forms]![frm_Results]![subfrm_shv_Results].form.controls(0)
```

Similarly, with a continuous form or such like :

```
= [Forms]![frm_Results]![subfrm_shv_Results].Form!Surname
```

The result is not editable, but you can get around this by setting the value in VBA.

Make sure you use the name of the subform control, not the the name of the form contained.